# How to distinguish different checkboxes in html/css

Tags: html, css, checkbox, rating-system

I'm working on making a thumbs-up/thumbs-down functionality, where pressing the thumb-up icon will turn the icon green and pressing the thumb-down icon will turn the icon red.  However, I don't  think I fully understand the 'checkbox' function  in my css file.

The code I currently have right now turns each thumb red upon clicking on them.  I take it this is happening because the two inputs I have near the bottom of my css file are conflicting and the red one comes last, hence it's getting priority.  What I'm struggling with though is finding a way to differentiate the two inputs.

```css
body {}

.main_box {
  background-color: #320082;
  height: 500px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ff4da6;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.glow {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.greencheckbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.redcheckbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 0);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(160, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MainBox.css" />
  <title>checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_box">
    <h1 class="glow">Wolfies</h1>

    <h2>560 Bungalow St</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="greencheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ion-icon name="thumbs-up" class="thumb"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="redcheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ion-icon name="thumbs-down" class="thumb"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since you can't check _both_ thumbs up and thumbs down (or can you?) the appropriate controls to start with, before styling, are radio buttons.  Using checkboxes instead creates _accessibility_ problems when a screen reader interprets the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that it's a style cascade issue. All you need to do is chain the selectors of the parent element to be specific for each input.

Like this:

```
.greencheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 0);
}

.redcheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(160, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
body {}

.main_box {
  background-color: #320082;
  height: 500px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ff4da6;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.glow {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.greencheckbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.redcheckbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

.greencheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 0);
}

.redcheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(160, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MainBox.css" />
  <title>checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_box">
    <h1 class="glow">Wolfies</h1>

    <h2>560 Bungalow St</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="greencheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ion-icon name="thumbs-up" class="thumb"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="redcheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <ion-icon name="thumbs-down" class="thumb"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### BETTER SOLUTION

Or you could add a class to each input to differentiate. This would make more sense, since you could move that `input` to any parent, and it would retain it's `:checked` state styles:

```css
.greencheckbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.redcheckbox {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  appearance: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

input[type=checkbox].green:checked {
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 0);
}

input[type=checkbox].red:checked {
  background-color: rgb(160, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<div class="greencheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="green thumbs-up">
  <ion-icon name="thumbs-up" class="thumb"></ion-icon>
</div>
<div class="redcheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="red thumbs-up">
  <ion-icon name="thumbs-down" class="thumb"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd tried input.greencheckbox[] but not .greencheckbox input[].  That worked, thank you!

Comment: @TheSwampyBogbeard added a better solution to your issue.